# For what integers $n$ is $-1$ an $n$th root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Can someone please verify my answer? I feel like I made it too complicated or I am missing something.

> For what integers $n$ is $-1$ an $n$th root of unity?

There are two values on the unit circle that give $-1$: $cos\pi$ and $sin\frac{3}{2}$. However, if $cisx=cosx+isinx$, then for any positive value $x$, $isinx\neq -1$.

For $z=cos\pi$, $n$ must be a multiple of $2$ so that $k$ can cancel out in $cis\frac{2k\pi}{n}$ leaving $z=cis\pi = -1$.

Therefore, the integers $n$ that make $-1$ an $n$th root of unity are even integers, since there will always exist an integer $k$ that will make $z=-1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $$(-1)^n=1$$

If $n$ is odd, the equation doesn't hold.

If $n$ is even, the equation holds.

Hence the answer is all even numbers.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not think about looking at it so simple like that, thanks. :) I will select your answer when it lets me.